# How to convert formula equation for functions in R (wilcox test) etc?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to make a function to accept different formula groups for the wilcox test. I do not understand how to change the formula equation to make it modular.

Example below:

```
library(rstatix)
library(dplyr)
data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth

df %>%
      group_by(dose) %>%
      wilcox_test(data =., len ~ supp) %>%
      adjust_pvalue(method = "bonferroni") %>%
      add_significance("p.adj")


# This Does Not Work

wilcox_test2 <- function(df,x,y){
return(df %>%
  group_by(dose) %>%
  wilcox_test(data =., x ~ y) %>%
  adjust_pvalue(method = "bonferroni") %>%
  add_significance("p.adj"))

}

wilcox_test2(df,df$len,df$supp)
```

Comment: Please include relevant libraries so that it is easier to reproduce your problem. I don't think `wilcox_text`, `adjust_pvalue` or `add_significance` are part of `base`.

Comment: sorry about that, I cleared my environment and that example ran, I believe these are the libraries. It's more the len ~ supp equation, which is agnostic to wilcox_test

Comment: instead of x and y as arguments, why not just use a `formula` and pass that to wilcox

Comment: I tried using formula, but as described below, I was unaware of managing strings versus vectors and pasting it properly to formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could pass the column names as argument and create the formula wihtin the function using `reformulate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(rstatix)
wilcox_test2 <- function(df, x, y){

 df %>%
   group_by(dose) %>%
   wilcox_test(data =., reformulate(y, response = x) ) %>%
   adjust_pvalue(method = "bonferroni") %>%
   add_significance("p.adj")

}
```

-testing

```
> wilcox_test2(df, "len", "supp")
# A tibble: 3 × 10
   dose .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic       p  p.adj p.adj.signif
* <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>       
1   0.5 len   OJ     VC        10    10      80.5 0.0232  0.0696 ns          
2   1   len   OJ     VC        10    10      88.5 0.00403 0.0121 *           
3   2   len   OJ     VC        10    10      49.5 1       1      ns
```

Comment: Wow, nice how does one find out about reformulate? I was busy using formula_test <- as.formula("len ~ supp") which doesn't work

Comment: @Jonathan with `as.formula`, you need `paste` i.e. `as.formula(paste(x, '~', y))`

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to pass the formula as one object:

```
wilcox_test3 <- function(df, form){
  return(df %>%
           group_by(dose) %>%
           wilcox_test(data =., form) %>%
           adjust_pvalue(method = "bonferroni") %>%
           add_significance("p.adj"))
  
}
wilcox_test3(df, len ~ supp)
# A tibble: 3 x 10
   dose .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic       p  p.adj p.adj.signif
* <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>       
1   0.5 len   OJ     VC        10    10      80.5 0.0232  0.0696 ns          
2   1   len   OJ     VC        10    10      88.5 0.00403 0.0121 *           
3   2   len   OJ     VC        10    10      49.5 1       1      ns
```